# Is there any way to get an email when ArcGIS Server services are stopped/down?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, administration

Occasionally, but all too often unfortunately, my AGS services just stop for no reason. I don't usually notice this until the users call me and ask why their maps have no data.

Is there any way (I was thinking Python) that I can get a response from AGS when services stop? How do other AGS users deal with this problem?

Comment: This is possible using ArcPy for ArcGIS Server (version 10.1). I am working on this issue on my side .For more help please check http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000v7000000 and let you know when the things will be perfect on my side : )

Comment: + 1 Do you need this for all services or specific services ? + Download ArcGIS Admin API for more details

Comment: I need it for all services really...but some are more important than others because some services deliver data to clients, and others are for internal use.

Comment: In such situation, what will be the purpose of Recycling or health check setting of any service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the same problem and I have this solution.
I writed in Python this code below ("localhost" in URL change to name of your AGS server):

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
import smtplib, urllib


from email import Encoders
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.Utils import formatdate
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMessage import MIMEMessage

COMMASPACE = ', '
SERVER = "IP adresss of post server"
FROM = "email adress from"
TO = ['1.email adress to','2.email adress to']

SUBJECT = "Some services on ArcGIS Server are down"

ServicesDown = []
CountOfServicesDown=0
TEXT="No problem"


# 1. Service - mapservice1
print "Test of service - mapservice1"
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})

f = opener.open("http://"localhost"/arcgis/rest/services/mapservice1/MapServer?wsdl")
code = urllib.urlopen("http://"localhost"/arcgis/rest/services/mapservice1/MapServer?wsdl"?wsdl").getcode()

if code is not 200:
    print "code: ", code
    print "mapservice1 is down"
    ServicesDown.append("mapservice1")
    CountOfServicesDown=CountOfServicesDown+1
else:
    print "service is OK"


# 2. Service - mapservice2
print "Test of service - mapservice2"
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})

f = opener.open("http://"localhost"/arcgis/rest/services/mapservice2/MapServer?wsdl")
code = urllib.urlopen("http://"localhost"/arcgis/rest/services/mapservice2/MapServer?wsdl"?wsdl").getcode()

if code is not 200:
    print "code: ", code
    print "mapservice1 is down"
    ServicesDown.append("mapservice2")
    CountOfServicesDown=CountOfServicesDown+1
else:
    print "service is OK"


print "\r\n"+"ServicesDown: ",ServicesDown
print "CountOfServicesDown= ",CountOfServicesDown

if CountOfServicesDown > 0:
    TEXT = "There are down this services: "+str(ServicesDown[:CountOfServicesDown])
    print "TEXT: ", TEXT


    # Prepare actual message

    message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)


    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
    print "\r\n"+"Email was send"

else:
    print "\r\n"+"There is no problem on AGS services"
```

Comment: Hi- Will it be possible to add the final log for the stopped service?

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look at the [ArcGIS Server Admin REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/index.html?overview.html) for this.

It looks like you could write a python script that runs on and schedule it to run periodically.  The script would [get all services in a cluster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/cluster.services.html), then to see if the service of interest is present, and if so check its [status](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/server-admin-api/status.html).

Otherwise, email a notification.

The script could also (re)start the service, if you wanted.

I'm not sure, but the [ArcPy admin package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Scripting_service_publishing_with_ArcPy/0154000005r2000000/) admin might provide a way to work with this API.

Comment: Thanks Kirk....I´ll have a look at that. That seems like a logical way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

We currently use this [ServiceMonitor](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15335) batch script, which does email notifications. We set it up as a Windows scheduled task so it runs every morning.

The only downside is that it takes quite a while to run since we have a large number of services, so we can't run it as often as we'd like. Maybe the Admin REST API or ArcPy would be quicker.

Comment: It seems as this works only on 10.0? Just curious if you use 10.1/10.2 and made it work for you.

Comment: I ran it briefly on 10.2 and it seemed to work okay, but we ran into other issues with our 10.2 server so I haven't tested it very extensively. I haven't tested it with 10.1 at all, but it should work on any version since it's basically just checking to see that the WSDL for each service is reachable.

Comment: I see, thank you for the info. If you ever get a chance to try Esri's Service Monitor (released just some months ago), I think it would suit your needs really well (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=848f48b0f88e4de7a036377197453efe). Here are some other useful resources - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73863/any-tool-to-monitor-arcgis-server-usage

Comment: Wow, that looks really useful -- thanks! The dynamic service discovery and monitoring sounds perfect for what we need.

Answer (score 1):

In free time I worked on a Python script that generates a web request to the ArcGIS server REST url and evaluates the response of the service. If the answer is negative will be sent an email alert to a specific e-mail address.

I think it is simple but useful for monitoring individual services of ArcGIS Server. I hope that is helpful for someone.

All info in our blog: http://oneteamgis.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/uno-script-python-che-monitora-i-servizi-di-arcgis-server/

Damiano

Comment: The blog post is no longer online, unfortunately.