# Any tool to monitor ArcGIS Server Usage

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I am using  ArcGIS Server 10.1 on AMI instance. I have around 10/12 simple map services (Used query layer in all services)

I want to check performance/time/statistics of map services in ArcGIS Server.

So is their any tool to monitor ArcGIS Services ??

**What I found so far :**

1.According to [http://ideas.arcgis.com](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Gzp&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%2bServer) their are few third party tools available.

2.Using windows task manager I can monitor only process not the services.

3.In 10.0 version its possible to see the statistics/min ,max time using 'statistics' tool in ArcGIS Server I think in 10.1 its not present

4.Using ArcPy I doubt its possible .Even I tried using [ArcGIS ADMIN API for server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005r1000000).

5.Screenshot of windows task manager (javaw.exe taking too much memory but its important to run the ArcGIS Server according to [this post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/90615-What-exactly-is-ArcGIS-Server-using-javaw.exe-for))

[image: ArcGIS Server 10.1_windows task manager]

**Update**

According to @Alex Tereshenkov answer I downloaded the tool but it work with Web adapter only. We do not have the Web adapter we are using reverse proxy at our end.

Found [this useful article](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/06/14/preparing-for-the-flood-will-your-gis-server-sink-or-swim/) for ArcGIS Server to test the load balance using Jmeter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[System Monitor Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=848f48b0f88e4de7a036377197453efe) from Esri is a great application for monitoring your services in more detail, ive used it a fair bit over last few months and its well worth installing.

It has a browser based console, stores all the metrics in MongoDB, good docco for both installing and using it. Monitors not only your ArcGIS Server and its services, but can look at the CPU/memory/resources of multiple machines, your database, ping HTTP, and you can view the metrics in nice charts and reports, get sent email alerts when resources are running low, along with much more.

Highly recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

I can really only expand on your 1st point (3rd party solutions). At this time the current version of Server (10.2) only has the number of running instances and number of requests available from the REST Admin. To the best of my knowledge there wont be any sort of "statistics" like you're asking for in the 10.2.1 release upcoming, but it is something that has been talked about and is being considered.

At this years UC (2013) I did a session on Python against the REST Admin API for Server.
You can [download it here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ecbb5717e8b04fa1a6c09fba7688cffa). Really the point of the session was an attempt I made at sucking log files down from a server and persisting them on disk in CSV format. Once you have a local static copy you could "perform analysis". Let me warn you, what I have in that presentation is only half-baked. It really is just proof of concept. It needs to be massaged and "made good".

If you want a "more polished" solution, try [Trevor Hart's solution](http://gdbgeek.wordpress.com/2013/01/23/exploring-arcgis-server-10-1-logs-part-2/) which follows the same principals (persist logs locally) into a SQL Database. You then can do some analysis with SQL Server tools or whatever can read a SQL database. I think he's done a great job on it.

So you can see, both approach involve getting a static copy of the logs and then using another tool to do the analysis. One using Python, the other .NET.

(note - there's nothing in the Admin toolkit to provide statistics like this. Just a tool that will show where requests are being made on a map service by generating extent polygons)

Answer (score 4):

We’re reluctant to post anything of a commercial nature here, but we felt it appropriate to round things out (given prior posts) and help paint a complete picture of what’s available.

Latitude Geographics (**Disclaimer**: my role is Product Manager at the company) has a well-established offering in this realm. [Geocortex Insight](http://www.geocortex.com/arcgis-server-software/geocortex-optimizer/) is a licensed product that provides insight into Esri ArcGIS platform implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Another great sample to add to the list KHibma provided is a JS-based web application that was shown at this Esri UC 2013. It can be downloaded [here](http://downloads.esri.com/Blogs/arcgisserver/ArcGIS_Server_for_Administrators_UC2013_Demos.zip) and the information about it is [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/08/23/demo-applications-arcgis-server-for-administrators-sessions-at-the-2013-user-conference/). The screenshot for the application GUI is below.

[image]

**EDIT:** There is another 3rd party product called [geoxmf](http://www.geoxmf.com/geoxmfweb2/pages/home/home.htm), I have not tested it myself, but it looks promising and there is support for 10.1 architecture.

Answer (score 2):

In free time I worked on a Python script that generates a web request to the ArcGIS server REST url and evaluates the response of the service.
If the answer is negative will be sent an email alert to a specific e-mail address.

I think it is simple but useful for monitoring individual services of ArcGIS Server.

All info in our blog:
http://oneteamgis.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/uno-script-python-che-monitora-i-servizi-di-arcgis-server/

Answer (score 1):

we just came across your question regarding monitoring. VESTRA has a COTS product that monitors ArcGIS Server Usage, SDE Usage and provides robust reporting and charting of the information gathered. http://products.vestra.com/geosystems-monitor/

In addition the GeoSystems Monitor will monitor the performance of your map services in ArcGIS Server as well as ArcGIS Online. The GeoSystems Monitor is an agentless monitoring tool that provides you with real-time information on all Esri servers and services running within your organization, including any 3rd party applications.

Comment: Since you are related to this product, you should add a disclaimer stating this. The stackexchange community tends to frown upon self promotion.

Comment: @Devdatta I see the disclaimer in the very first word of this post. Heather, by editing your [profile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27425/heather-croom) you can provide a description of you, your company, and anything else you like, along with contact information. That would give you a little more (and better) exposure and perhaps limit misunderstandings. Welcome to our site!

Answer (score 1):

Have just seen on one of the Esri videos from [Dev Summit '14](http://video.esri.com/series/166/2014-esri-international-developer-summit-plenary) that in the 10.2.3 (I think it will be released under this version notation) that comes this summer, there will be Services Monitor piece of functionality embedded into the core of ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 1):

For your second point in windows task manager you can see the service associated at process arcsoc.exe: visualize column 'command line'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Esri Professional Services as developed a free reporting tool specifically designed for analyzing ArcGIS server and service logs called [System Log Parser](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=90134fb0f1c148a48c65319287dde2f7).  From the description:

> System Log Parser is an ArcGIS for Server (10.1+) log query and analyzer tool.
>   When run, it connects to an ArcGIS for Server instance on port 6080 as an 
>   administrator, retrieves all logs from a time duration (specified as an input), 
>   analyzes the information then produces a spreadsheet version of the data that 
>   summarizes the service statistics.
>
> System Log Parser is a desktop application that utilizes a graphical user interface
>   but also supports a scriptable back-end for report creation automation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one..'iGeoAsset' monitors ArcGIS services, OGC services, Geodatabases (Oracle and SQL Server). One of the cool features in this tool is it not only monitors, but it is capable of restarting the arcgis services automatically if they stop working. It will also collect ArcGIS Statistics, performing analytics with arcgis server logs etc.

http://www.igeoasset.com

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

At Innovate we also had a similar need for a number of our clients that have ArcServer.  So we have developed a monitoring, load testing and notification tool for ArcServer.  Feel free to check it out at http://servermonitor.innovateteam.com/.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Frank.  I have edited out your contact info according to our site policy.  Your [profile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/edit/35395) is the preferred place to display that information.